# cocos2d-js android devices don't respond to touch events, iOS and web does work with touch events

Tags: javascript, android, touch, cocos2d-js, coco2d-x

I am using cocos2D-JS to port my 2D game to multiple platforms.

The problem I am having is whenever I run and test the game on an android device, it won't respond to touch events at all.  With the exact same code, I can build and run it on iOS devices and the touch works.  When I run it on the web, touch events work fine with iOS or android devices.

This is how I am implementing my touch events: --------------

with in the main gameScene

```
(cc.Scene.extent({

onEnter: function(){
...
...
...

cc.eventManager.addListener({

    event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
    setTouchEnabled: true,

    onTouchBegan: function(touch,event){
        // Do Stuff
        // Do More Stuff
    },
    .....
    .....
},this);
```

Like I said iOS and web is responding just fine to these touch events, just android devices are not.  Also mouse events are working fine on all platforms.

Any ideas?
Thank You

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo: you should use **extend** from cc.Scene.